# Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task` System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, webforms

I have created a Web Forms application using Visual Studio 2017, .NET 4.6.1 and EF 6.2. Whenever I run the application locally it works fine however when I publish the application and upload to our IIS server I am getting the error shown in the screen shot.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvOTn.png)

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!!0,Boolean>>)'.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!!0,Boolean>>)'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:


[MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<!!0> System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable`1<!!0>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1<System.Func`2<!!0,Boolean>>)'.]
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.<GetUserAggregateAsync>d__6c.MoveNext() +0
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start(TStateMachine& stateMachine) +174
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`6.GetUserAggregateAsync(Expression`1 filter) +199
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29.MoveNext() +150
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +13847892
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +61
   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.AsyncHelper.RunSync(Func`1 func) +212
   SupplierPortal.Account.Login.LogIn(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Kobi\Dropbox\Development\WebForms\SupplierPortal_git\SupplierPortal\Account\Login.aspx.cs:39
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +138
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +150
   System.Web.UI.<ProcessRequestMainAsync>d__523.MoveNext() +7834
```

So far I have tried:

- downgrading EF to an earlier version.
- checking for any missing using statements.
- removing and adding the associated .dll files from my references.
- recoding the application to target an earlier version of .NET
- manually adding the link to the .dll files in the web.config
- setting all referenced .dlls to copy local
- have ensured the application pool is set to V4.0
- have ensured IIS has latest .NET installed

I have noticed that this line in the stack trace:

```
SupplierPortal.Account.Login.LogIn(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\Kobi\Dropbox\Development\WebForms\SupplierPortal_git\SupplierPortal\Account\Login.aspx.cs:39
```

References a file path that does not exist on the web server, rather my local system, however I cannot find any properties within VS to change or set this.

There is another web forms application running on the IIS server which targets earlier versions of .NET and EF. This application is running fine, however it is my understanding that the asynchronous methods which seem to be causing the problem in my application were introduced in a later version of EF.

Any help with the issue is massively appreciated I have been racking my brain for the past few days!

Comment: You need to include the relevant code in your question. The stack trace tells you what line the error is.

Comment: @mason the code causing the error is default .NET/EF authorisation/authentication code, I am using web forms authentication to authenticate users of my application. I do not believe the issue is with the code itself but rather the configuration/publish. The application compiles and runs as expected on my local machine it is only throwing the exception when published and running on IIS.

Comment: @mason the application runs on the server, but as soon as any standard .NET/EF login code is called the app falls over.

Comment: I think problem not in EF, Check your **app pool .Net CLR version** and make sure it targets **V4.0**

Comment: @Ahmed Ragheb the app pool is currently targeting V4.0 and the server has the .NET 4.6.1 installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pulling my hair out over this, I eventually created a fresh EC2 instance. The app ran without issue once uploaded. I'm assuming there is some configuration issue with the older instance.